# Postgres, error with query

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, postgresql

I do one query and I have syntax error. But for me I do all right.

Where I have error?

Thanks!

```
$str = "Moscow";
$data = $ci->crud_model->query(
    'select * from "Cities" where  "defaultName" ilike  %'.$str.'%'
);
```

Query is : `select * from "Cities" where "defaultName" ilike %Moscow%`

Comment: `ilike`? Is it a more personified version of the SQL `like`?

Comment: @CodeNewbie: Only PostGreSql provide the key word ILIKE can be used instead of LIKE to make the match case-insensitive according to the active locale.

Comment: @user2051503: See my answer I have given example of ILIKe... Hope u will understand

Comment: It would be more useful if you actually included the text of the error the question refers to. Always do this.

Comment: Also, read http://stackoverflow.com/q/5857386/398670 and http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: @CraigRinger Good find. Added reference and better code to my answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `LIKE`/`ILIKE` operator takes two strings as its arguments. That is, the pattern has to be a quoted string, not just directly in the SQL query.

So instead of:

```
"defaultName" ilike %Moscow%
```

You need:

```
"defaultName" ilike '%Moscow%'
```

In PHP, you should be (at the very least) escaping the input to avoid SQL Injection. Probably CodeIgniter has facilities for escaping, or using parameterised queries, but at the very least you should do this:

```
$str = "Moscow";
$data = $ci->crud_model->query(
    'select * from "Cities" where  "defaultName" ilike  \'%'.pg_escape_string($str).'%\''
);
```

**EDIT** Per Craig Ringer's comment, the correct ways to escape or build safe queries with CodeIgniter are [covered in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5857481/157957).

This is probably the simplest (note that the query parameter is automatically a string, and doesn't need extra quotes):

```
$str = "Moscow";
$data = $ci->crud_model->query(
    'select * from "Cities" where  "defaultName" ilike ?',
    array('%' . $str . '%')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to surround %moscow% with quotes:

> select * from "Cities" where "defaultName" ilike' %Moscow%'

Comment: Thanks! Your post is very helpful for me!
my solution is    `$data = $ci->crud_model->query("select * from \"Cities\" where \"defaultName\" ilike' %$str%'");`

Answer (score -1):

The key word ILIKE can be used instead of LIKE to make the match case-insensitive according to the active locale. This is not in the SQL standard.
Make it LIKE in place of ilike

```
$str = "Moscow";
$data = $ci->crud_model->query('select * from Cities where defaultName LIKE  %$str%');
```

Then you Query will be

```
select * from Cities where defaultName LIKE '%Moscow%';
```

For ILIKE: 
Example -

```
SELECT first_name,last_name FROM customer WHERE first_name ILIKE 'BAR%';
```

Here it will return row as per this condition:

The  BAR% pattern matches any string that begins with BAR, Bar, BaR, etc. If you use the LIKE operator instead, the query will not return any row.
 Reference: http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-like/

Comment: what err you see...?
you run that query in database and what err its showing ?

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "%"
LINE 1: select * from "Cities" where "defaultName" LIKE %Moscow%