# how to check sql injection in codigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, sql-injection

I am working on codeigniter project. How can I know queries function in my models are preventing the sql injection. 
Even I'm using different ways to insert data but how can i make sure that which one is safe .

Here's my code:

```
1) *****************
    $data = array(
   'name' => $_POST['name'],
   'email' => $_POST['email'],
   'phone' => $_POST['phone'],
   'city' => $_POST['city'],
   'current_salary' => $_POST['current_salary'],
   'expected_salary' => $_POST['expected_salary'],
   'reume_link' => $file_name,
   'status' => 0,
   );
   $this->db->insert('my_table_name', $data);

2) **************************
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT  distinct(name) as name   FROM `my_table_name` WHERE city like "%'.$_POST['state'].'%" ');
    $res = $query->result_array();

3) **************************    
    $query = $this->db->query("insert into my_table_name(nid,sid,cid,data) values('766','$sid',1,'".$_POST['adm_name']."')");
```

> Are the codeigniter function prevent sql injection default or I strictly need to use prepare statement / bind parameter.
>
> Are the simple  CI function not safe to use ?

Comment: You should always use prepared statements.

Comment: (1) is perfectly fine. Both (2) and (3) good examples of what not to do. It's not even more readable to eschew the reliable approach. So what's the purpose of this question?

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857386/how-to-avoid-sql-injection-in-codeigniter);

Comment: @mario  things you explain really helpful for me . You mean $this->db->query('my query ') needs to use escape function for every entity.

Comment: 1) is fine each var will be escaped correctly and will be safe. For extra safety you can tell it the use the mysqli or pdo libraries which will use prepared statements. 2 + 3) Don't EVER use queries like this in a production environment.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$this->db->escape_str` for every variable you put inside your query. Another option (even a better one) is to use prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to use prepared statements -

```
$sql = 'SELECT distinct(name) name FROM `my_table_name` WHERE city like ?';
$query = $this->db->query($sql, array("%$_POST[state]%"));
```

means you have to substitute actual data with ? marks and pass it in the form of array as a second parameter.

Most of ActiveRecord methods (like `insert`, `get` and such) are safe too, as long as you are following guidelines.

Comment: @mario said my first way (in my question is perfect ) . can you advise how can i check it to make sure .

Comment: Please let's not go down this road.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using CodeIgniter's [Active Record](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html) methods it'll automatically escape queries for you to prevent injection.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('table_name');
$this->db->where('column_name', $val1);
$this->db->get();
```

If you don't want to use CI Active Records then there's a function i.e [`$this->db->escape()`](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html) in CI

```
$data1 = $this->db->escape($data1);
$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE var = '$data1'");
```

Or you can use query bindings as

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE var = ?';
$this->db->query($sql, array($var));
```

Even instead of using `$_POST` and `$_GET` CI have its method of `$this->input->post()` and `$this->input->get()` respectively

Comment: i am getting different way to prevent but nobody is  advising how can i check .

Comment: What you needed to be advised can you elaborate

Comment: i want to make sure all my queries are safe are prevent the sql injection so how can i test..  dosen't matter whatever method i am using

Comment: Then you need to use Active records instead or need to escape your variables before querying http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857386/how-to-avoid-sql-injection-in-codeigniter?lq=1

Comment: @Uchiha, I need you help. Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38607368/how-to-implement-in-to-prepare-statement?noredirect=1#comment64603092_38607368

Answer (score -1):

For protection always use `$this->input->post('name_of_input')` and `$this->input->get('name_of_input')` instead of `$_POST[] & $_GET[]`

Answer (score -1):

check this [link](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html) for documentation

in config.php set

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = True;
```

or use xss_clean in validation, check the [link](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html) for documentation