# Does CodeIgniter automatically prevent SQL injection when using function like insert(), update() , where(), order_by()?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3, sql-injection

**Note** :My question is **not a duplicate question** for [Does CodeIgniter automatically prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615792/does-codeigniter-automatically-prevent-sql-injection) or [how to avoid sql injection in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857386/how-to-avoid-sql-injection-in-codeigniter) because it asked `query()` function. I am asking function like `insert(), update() , where(), order_by()`?

I am asking that following types of queries also automatically prevent SQL injection?

01.

```
$data = array(
        'title' => $title,
        'name' => $name,
        'date' => $date
);

$this->db->where('school', $school);
$this->db->update('mytable', $data);
```

02

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('table_name');
$this->db->where('pro_name', $pro_name);        
$this->db->order_by($pro_type, 'desc');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```

**Assume that all variables are GET or POSTS values.**

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857386/how-to-avoid-sql-injection-in-codeigniter?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @GhanshyamBhava It is not a duplication question too that quetion too because it is also asked the `query()` function. I am asking about function like` insert(), update() , where(), order_by()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to avoid sql injection in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857386/how-to-avoid-sql-injection-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeIgniter's Active Record methods https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html automatically escape queries for you, to prevent injection.

You may find answer in here https://stackoverflow.com/a/5857481/4895810