# codeigniter sql injection are there are any possible way to find out

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

In our application, which is build in codeigniter 2.8, a hacker hacked a specific page without sql injection. How can we find out the root cause of this issue? If you have any ideas on your end, please share.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to avoid sql injection in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857386/how-to-avoid-sql-injection-in-codeigniter)

Comment: @DevsiOdedra If you really want to you can still create plenty of possible SQL injections ;)

Comment: @DevsiOdedra what makes you think that simply using a framework removes all attack vectors?

Comment: Thanks, we used only query builder all sql injections removed default codeigniter process, but hacker sent screen shot for our web application page, i don't know how is possible to go without user credentials

Comment: Is it  still possibility of sql injection if we have only used CI's query builder?